# Port forward from computer (not router management)?

Tags: windows, router, port-forwarding

Since applications can set up port forwarding rules in my home network's router, I'm assuming I can as well via a command or something of that sort, correct?

Here's my dilemma: I have a Belkin wireless router that loves to "disappear". I'm not sure why, but the remote management of it seems to stop after less than a day pretty consistently. The router will continue to function, but I won't be able to manage it.

I need to forward a particular port to a machine on this network, but I can't power-cycle the router (typically the only way to get the management address (192.168.2.1) to respond again).

So back to the original question; can I set a forward like applications do? Or for that matter, is there an application that I can get to allow me to manage that from the (Windows) PC?

Thanks so much in advance, and all apologies knowing nothing about networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPnP Port Works](http://www.wiseorbit.com/projects/upnppw/) saves the day, and yeah... I'll get a new router.

Comment: Just so you understand - from your description, your router is losing it's web interface for management. There's no reason to assume that on a consumer-grade router, that any other method of management (like UPnP) would work either. That's why you were getting answers to replace your router. I'm glad you found a tool to help you.

Answer (score 5):

If it's failing like that, there's a good chance the router is going flaky...my response would be to replace the router.

If I'm reading your question correctly, you can't forwards ports on the computer from the computer. The router is what mediates the connections between the Internet and your internal systems. Otherwise you'd be in a lot more trouble with what malware can and can't do to your router.

The real answer is to get a new router and replace the one going flaky. Home routers are notorious for dying in a short amount of time, at least at my house. I used to have the integrated WAP/Router units (less than ~100 to $150) die within a year or two and replace them.

Anything else is a kludge that's waiting for it to finish dying on you.

Comment: If you're looking for a router review: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html

Comment: Why do applications ask if you would like for them to try creating a mapping for you then? Isn't it UPnP or some such? I know something exists to do this, because I've got entries in my port forwarding list that I didn't put there and applications seem to be able to do it when they're smarter than me about why I can't get connectivity.

Comment: Okay, let me reword it. You've probably enabled UPnP, yes. And it's a bad idea. Security wise. Google searches can tell you that you should disable it, and you can manually set port forwarding on devices (it's not hard to do). And it still doesn't negate that your router is flaking out on you. You should replace it rather than try duct taping holes in a sinking boat.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, really. I understand why I should get a new router, but even assuming I do that today when I get home from work, these responses so far have been pretty useless to solve my issue. They've instead pointed me to a whole separate problem. It's almost as if over on SO, if I said that I couldn't figure out why something wasn't working in FoxPro and the only answer I could get was "Use C#. FoxPro's not doing you any good." regardless of the fact that I needed to get past the issue in FoxPro for a client's systems that I had no control over. Just expected more, I guess.

Comment: I would suggest replacing it, it is going bad. if it is for your house, get a basic wireless inexpensive Linksys E1000 or E3000

Comment: You have a failing router. It's not like "I can't get this in Foxpro" and the answer is "Use C#." You came to a sysadmin area to ask the equivalent of "I have a flat tire and need to know what kind of fix-a-flat I should use." The answer isn't to pump the tire up with patch stuff. It's *replace the tire.*

Comment: No one was telling you to use a different technology. Think of it like this - you wanted to drive your car, but you had to jump-start it every time. You wanted a way to jump-start it without having to pop the hood. You were getting answers to replace your battery, not try a different car.

Comment: Hah! Nice, @Bart. I should reload the page before posting a new comment next time, to see if someone already did a good car analogy.

Comment: @Bart: Actually, no. Your analogy would need to become: I have a flat tire and someone rolls by with a truck full of different shape, size, and color cans of Fix-A-Flat; so I ask the guy "which can will get me to the tire place to get this taken care of given my _current_ circumstances?" By comparison your answers have been "Whoa! That's really flat! ... Good luck!"

Comment: You came asking for software to manage a dying router. Stop at the store and buy a new one rather than kludge together a stopgap measure. That was my answer, because after a couple decades working on people's systems and seeing what you're asking, you're not asking for a solution to that specific problem so much as you're asking for more problems. It's not hard and it's not usually a huge hardship to just replace the router rather than retrofit a crap solution to your situation and make things more convoluted.

Comment: You can haggle all you want over the answer, if you're happy with some stopgap measure that perpetuates the wrong way of doing things, fine, no point in arguing over metaphors and how applicable to your way of doing things. You went to SF where people deal with similar situations, although with higher-end stuff, for a living. We cringe at UPnP for a reason. We advocate replacing a $50 router for a reason. If you don't like those reasons, I'm sorry. But there are reasons for it. Ignore it. Follow it. Do whatever you want. Free advice. Worth what you paid.